# Data Archival of a few tables from MySQL database to Parquet file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: mysql, azure-data-factory, parquet

I am new to ADF and looking for suggestions on how to handle the following situation.

We have a requirement to archive data from few tables in MySQL database to parquet files and post-archival purge the entries in MySQL tables. The entries to be archived and purged are driven off of 1 main table in the database. (Meaning rest of the tables must be joined to this main table's PK and filter with creation timestamp of main table). Each table must create a parquet file in storage account.

1. How do I identify and transfer the records from all tables which are related to entries of main table older than 6 months?
2. How to handle transaction? Do not want to have partial tables completing data transfer for an entry in main table.

I tried creating copy activity, but dint know how to join all the tables in ADF. If I use stored procedure to join all the dependent tables, the result set is huge. Also, dint know how to split the result set to 1 parquet file per table.

Answer (score 0):

Start from there

[Copy data from MySQL using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mysql?tabs=data-factory)